# Why does X11 send two events in the case of _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW changing value?

Tags: c, x11, xlib

So I wrote a simple test program to track the value of the _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW property before I implemented in my main program. Though I noticed a strange behavior, whenever I switch what window is currently in focus I get 2 events that notify about the value of _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW changing instead of 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main(void){
    Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    Window root = XDefaultRootWindow(dpy);

    XSelectInput(dpy, root, PropertyChangeMask);

    XEvent ev;
    while(True){
        XNextEvent(dpy, &ev);
        if(strcmp("_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW", XGetAtomName(dpy, ev.xproperty.atom)) == 0){
            Atom type;
            int format;
            unsigned long items, bytesLeft;
            Window *value;
            XGetWindowProperty(dpy, root, ev.xproperty.atom, 0, 1, False,
                AnyPropertyType, &type, &format, &items, &bytesLeft, (unsigned char**)&value);

            printf("active window id: %u\n", *value);
        }
    }

    XCloseDisplay(dpy);
}
```

Here's what the output of running this program is. Obviously the lines beginning with # are comments I added to clarify what's going on

```
[zee@zeeDT test]> ./test
#started program in terminal here
#switch from terminal to text editor
active window id: 171966465
active window id: 171966465
#switch from text editor to terminal
active window id: 130023431
active window id: 130023431
```

Edit: after more testing I found that the numbers also aren't always consistent, for example if I switch from my text editor to the terminal sometimes the output will look like the above but sometimes it will also look like this. Why would the id ever be 0?

```
active window id: 0
active window id: 130023431
```

Comment: I have the same issue :(